# MINImusic-Player argument passing

Tags: jquery

I'm working with this (https://github.com/codovate/MINImusic-Player) music player. I can pass elements value inside the script like that.

```
$(".example").musicPlayer({
elements: ['artwork', 'information', 'controls', 'progress', 'time', 'volume'], 
autoPlay: true,
volume:70,
});
```

How can i get and pass current time value using this script?

Comment: you mean get current time of the song

Comment: i want to get current time from one page's player and set current time to other page's player. Maybe i can get time but can't find a way to set player time with my custom value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var voice = $('#voice')[0];
     voice.load();
 voice.onloadedmetadata=function(){
     console.log(voice.duration);   
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I don't want to get the duration.I want to pass my custom duration value through the script by which i can change the duration of currently played music.